# Retain formatting when saving file as DOC

Tags: powershell, ms-word

Successfully extracted all informed required from Word doc. But when we save the final results of output as DOC we lose all formatting, how can we retain that formatting (for e.g. if numbering was done, or bullet points)?

```
$found = $doc.Range($startPosition, $endPosition)
$found | Out-File "D:\Found.doc"
```

We want to save the final results in CSV so that it can be imported into database for further processing.

Comment: Normally, the term CSV refers to a text file having "comma separated values". You can create a Word document with comma separate values, and that can include formatting. But in order to retain the formatting the document must be saved as a Word document. I don't know whether you can actually use that for importing into a database. If you want to write each value to a field in the database I don't see how you can retain the formatting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving a file the extension `.doc` doesn't magically make it a Word document. `Out-File` creates plain-text files, so of course all formatting is lost when writing content of your Word document out as plain text.

Copy the selected range to a new Word document and save that. Something like this should work (untested, though):

```
$newdoc = $wd.Documents.Add()
$doc.Range($startPosition, $endPosition).Copy()
$newdoc.Content.Paste()
$newdoc.SaveAs("D:\found.docx")
$newdoc.Close()
```

I don't think Word provides CSV export as readily as Excel, so it would probably require a custom export routine. You need to provide more information about the data you're trying to export for us to help with that.

Comment: got this message - Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass] does not contain a method named 'Paste'.

Comment: @user3657339 Try `$newdoc.Selection.Paste()` or `$newdoc.Content.Paste()` then.